# How to add custom discount to order total in drupal commerce

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I used the custom price field in order entity with this name : `field_commerce_order_off` for get custom discount from admin in " admin/commerce/orders/add ".
I try to use this hook :

```
<?php

// Implements hook_commerce_order_presave().

function commerce_deposit_account_commerce_order_presave($order) {

    if($order->field_commerce_order_off){
        $discount = $order->field_commerce_order_off['und'][0]['amount'];
        $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($order->commerce_line_items['und'][0]['line_item_id']);

        // Add the discount as a price component
        $line_item->commerce_unit_price->data = commerce_price_component_add(
            $order->commerce_order_total['und'][0]['amount'],
            'discount',
            array(
                'amount' => $discount * -1,
                'currency_code' => 'IRR',
                'data' => array()
            ),
            0 // NOT included already in the price
        );
    }
}
?>
```

But it doesn't work!
I don't want to add discount to `line_item`, I want to add discount to order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fees to add a negative fee to an order.